# How do I make a paginator class move within 1 page (HTML & CSS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pagination

I acquired the theme infusion from the internet. You can see examples of it here http://www.html5xcss3.com/2014/06/infusion-responsive-html5-theme.html

or a live preview here http://peterfinlan.com/infusion/

.. I am having problems making the paginator class move. Obviously when one of those elements is clicked it is supposed to move and show the rest of the team.

I realize the code on that theme just displays the 3 pages using that class and that no actual motion is available.

I want to know what needs to be done for that area to move in either direction when one of those elements are clicked.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you have all the js files in js folder ?

Comment: I am sure I have all the files.. I have also looked at the demo versions online if they differ to my version and the versions online don't move either.

But the classes are allocated to the elements. The whole things just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a slider or carousel in javascript or css - some [options are here](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=slider%20carousel):

- http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/
- http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/
- http://flexslider.woothemes.com/basic-carousel.html

Comment: OP wants to fix the theme already installed. You don't even provide help on this problem. You only provide external links.

Comment: The original theme doesn't include the needed components; I provided links that help him install the needed component - that's the solution. How is this not helping?

Comment: The theme includes `jQuery OwlCarousel v1.3.2`, for exemple. Did you checked what it really contains ?